# Newton's method for roots of multiplicity

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

Any suggestion? I have no idea what the question is asking.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just write down the formula $n(x)=x-f(x)/f'(x)$ in the case $f(x)=g(x)^2$ and compare to what you get when you write down $x-g(x)/g'(x)$ directly. You should find that you are adjusting your approximation in the former case by only half the amount that you do in the latter.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** To see what's happening, calculate explicitly let $f(x)=x^2$. Start with say $x_1=1$. You will find that the convergence is somewhat slow, or at least a lot slower than Newton "usually" is.

Then generalize.

Comment: Well, in this case $g(x)=x$ and the corresponding Newton's method iteration function is $n(x)=0$ - i.e., you get to the exact root in one step from any starting value. :)

Comment: Yes, but applying the Newton Method blindly to $x^2$ gets you the sequence of approximations $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\dots$, instead of the "characteristic" roughly doubling the number of correct decimal digits for each iteration.